# Select rows that based on a where statement

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause

How can I select values that have the word "link" in them and make them in category1 and "popcorn" in them to make them category2 and all else put in category3?

Here is a sample but my actual dataset has hundreds of rows

```
data = {'model': [['Lisa', 'link'], ['Lisa 2', 'popcorn'], ['telephone', 'rabbit']],
        'launched': [1983, 1984, 1991]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['model', 'launched'])
```

Desired

```
 Model                 launched         category
 ['Lisa', 'link']        1983             1
 ['Lisa 2', 'popcorn']   1984             2
 ['telephone', 'rabbit'] 1991             3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use apply function:

Create a def:

```
def get_categories(row):
    if 'link' in row.model:
        return 1
    elif 'popcorn' in row.model:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3
```

And then call it like that:

```
df['category'] = df.apply(get_categories, axis=1)
df
```

Outputs:

```
    model           launched    category
0   [Lisa, link]        1983    1
1   [Lisa 2, popcorn]   1984    2
2   [telephone, rabbit] 1991    3
```

**EDIT:**

Based on @gred_data comment, you can actually do that in one line in order to increase performance:

```
df['category'] = df.model.apply(lambda x: 1 if 'link' in x else 2 if 'popcorn' in x else 3)
df
```

Gets you the same result.

Comment: this is the most pythonic way to go about it, but note that it would be more performant to run the `get_categories` method on the model column directly. Doing this inline would look like: `df['category'] = df.model.apply(lambda x: 1 if 'link' in x else 2 if 'popcorn' in x else 3)`

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to set `category` to `1` or `2` depending on whether `'link'` or `'popcorn'` is contained in a given list. Set `default` to `3` for the case where neither of them are contained:

```
import numpy as np
c1 = ['link' in i for i in df.model]
c2 = ['popcorn' in i for i in df.model]
df['category'] = np.select([c1,c2], [1,2], 3)

              model       launched  category
0         [Lisa, link]      1983         1
1    [Lisa 2, popcorn]      1984         2
2  [telephone, rabbit]      1991         3
```